# Is "\NearestEven" available in frama-c Aluminium-20160501?

Tags: frama-c

The ACSL [implementation](http://frama-c.com/download/acsl-implementation-Aluminium-20160501.pdf) (Version 1.11 Implementation in Aluminium-20160501) lists `\NearestEven` as a rounding mode (page 23). However, it doesn't appear to be still available at runtime. When I ran the following code:

```
/*@   requires 0x1p-967 <= C <= 0x1p970;
  @   ensures \result == \round_double(\NearestEven, (x+y)/2) ;
  @ */

double average(double C, double x, double y) {
  if (C <= abs(x))
    return x/2+y/2;
  else
    return (x+y)/2;
}
```

using the following command: `frama-c -wp -wp-rte -wp-prover coq avg.c`, I get: `[wp] user error: Builtin \NearestEven not defined`. None of the other rounding modes was available either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The manual you refer to indicates what is supported by Frama-C's kernel. This does not imply that all plugins (or even any plugin) know how to deal with such a construction. In your particular case, WP indeed does not support `\NearestEven`.

With `-wp-model +float`, you might be able to work on a goal such as `\result == (double)((x+y)/2)`, which will very probably use nearest even for the rounding involved by the cast to `double` (but I have to admit that the paragraph on Float arithmetic model in [WP's manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-wp-manual.pdf) is a bit succinct). This will of course not work if you want to use another rounding mode, for which I think only the Jessie plugin, if there is a version compatible with Aluminium somewhere, will be able to do something.

Note that for handling such proofs, you'll need to resort to [Gappa](http://gappa.gforge.inria.fr/) and/or [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/). The prover used in WP by default (Alt-Ergo) is unlikely to discharge much proof obligations related to floating-point computations.

Comment: Thanks! Is Jessie plugin still supported? The Aluminium version of frama-c doesn't appear to come with Jessie and I tried all the way back to Nitrogen and didn't see it either. The Jessie [webpage](http://krakatoa.lri.fr/) doesn't make it clear where to get it either.

Comment: I'm pretty unsure of the exact status. Sources of [why3](http://why3.lri.fr/) show a `jessie3` directory with a minimalistic support of C. I guess that you have to restrict to what Why3 supports directly, i.e. plain references and arrays, without any alias, no gotos, etc.. If you're mainly interested with floating-point accuracy, this fragment might be sufficient, though. However, jessie3 is apparently not installed by the corresponding opam package. I haven't checked whether you can easily install it by compiling why3 directly.